# call function for every row of *ngFor angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor

I have to display a table and call a function for every row of table and the function called once for a row.

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of mf.data"  >
          <td >
            <button (click)="remove(item)" class="btn btn-danger">x</button>
          </td>
          <td>{{item.name}}</td>
          <td>{{item.email}}</td>
          <td class="text-right">{{item.age}}</td>
          <td>{{item.city | uppercase}}</td>
        </tr>
```

Please suggest how will I implement this functionality??

Comment: what you want exactly to happen

Comment: above code looks correct,what is the error you are getting?

Comment: I want to call a function for every row of that *ngfor??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a directive

```
@Directive({ selector: '[invoke]'})
class InvokeDirective {
  @Output() invoke:EventEmitter = new EventEmitter();
  ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.invoke.emit(null);
  }
}
```

And the use it like

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of mf.data" (invoke)="myFunction(item)" >
```

Comment: Is there anything built in provided by angular @Gunter??

Comment: Don't think so.

Comment: Will u please explain how will i Integrate with my component?? I am novice  in angular 2

Comment: That's the 2nd code snipped. `myFunction(...)` is a method in your component that gets called when `*ngFor` addes a `<tr>`

Comment: I have added directive and function but its not working

Comment: Did you register the directive in `@NgModule({, ...declarations[InvokeDirective]})`?

Comment: I have added that directive in shared module and imported it my @NGModule

Comment: Try changing `ngAfterContentInit` to `ngOnInit`. Add a `console.log('xxx')` and tell if it's printed to the browser console, if not, also try to add `console.log('xxx')` to the constructor.

Comment: Sorry!! I forgot the `[]` in the selector.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135842/discussion-between-keshav-and-gunter-zochbauer).

Comment: Thank you very much. This helped me.